# WordPress get_title from category

Tags: php, wordpress, post, content-management-system, categories

I was wondering how to get the title/img/content of some random article, but from specific category.

For an example: 
I have 3 categories A,B and C and I have a image slider on my blog. 
I want to show on the slider ONLY those articles who are in category A, not B and C. 
How can I make that happen ? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below example should get you started.  It basically calls the get_posts() function with some criteria.

- Return 5 Posts
- Random Order
- From Specificed Category

Then we run a foreach on the returned posts to do what we want.  You don't have to run a foreach, in the below example $rand_posts will hold an array post objects with which you can do what you want.

You can take a look at the codex and change the arguments, criteria, to whatever you'd like.

[Wordpress Codex - Get Posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts)

```
<?php
    $cat_id = // Your category ID.
    $args = array('numberposts' => 5, 'orderby' => 'rand', category => $cat_id);
    $rand_posts = get_posts($args);
    foreach($rand_posts as $post) : ?>
    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
        // Access all other post information here just like in a normal look. (Ex. the_content(), the_excerpt(), etc, etc
<?php endforeach; ?>
```